# How do I animate a CorePlot plot space using UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, core-plot

I know that one can turn on scrolling in a coreplot plot space as follows:

```
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
```

but this only activates one-to-one finger to graph motion. Is it currently possible to use coreplot with a UIScrollView to achieve the elasticity effects (inertia, deceleration, bounce)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will want to animate the change of the underlying transform matrix. Have a look at `CATransform3D` and `CATransform3DMakeScale`. You can wrap this up in an Core Animation Block.

Comment: OK, so I can create animations that change a view's transformation matrix over time, but this is not the question. 

I'm specifically looking for a way to tie into the transformations that would happen to a view controlled by a UIScrollView. I don't want to reinvent that particular wheel.

Comment: Maybe you want to implement UIScrollViewDelegate methods and act upon certain events?